# How to extract all variants of relational XML for an index

Tags: xslt, indexing

I set up an index with places. The output should be from the bigger to the smaller, i.e.

> New York, Manhattan, Wall Street

The problem is, that some times streets don't belong to one district but to two and sometimes there is no district at all but the streets are listed directly under the city.

So whenever i get an idno and use it on a code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listplaces>
    <place>
       <placeName type="city">City A</placeName>
        <idno>CA</idno>
    </place>
    <place>
        <placeName type="district">District B</placeName>
        <idno>DB</idno>
        <belongsTo active="CA" passive="DB"/>
    </place>
    <place>
        <placeName type="district">District C</placeName>
        <idno>DC</idno>
        <belongsTo active="CA" passive="DC"/>
    </place>
    <place>
        <placeName type="street">Street D</placeName>
        <idno>SD</idno>
        <belongsTo active="DB" passive="SD"/>
        <belongsTo active="DC" passive="SD"/>
    </place>
    <place>
        <placeName type="street">Street E</placeName>
        <idno>SE</idno>
        <belongsTo active="CA" passive="SE"/>
    </place>
</listplaces>
```

This should output according to the idno

```
idno CA: City A
idno DB: City A, District B
idno DC: City A, District C
idno SD: City A, District B, Street D
idno SD: City A, District C, Street D
idno SE: City A, Street E
```

The problem is, when I'm in the lowest level, to create the output in the right order – to follow all @active relations to the top. I found a solution where I concat the active placeName always to the left of a string. But I have no clue how to get XSLT to deal with all possible variants and create accordingly as many strings as needed.

(I use XSLT 3.0)

Comment: You have `idno DB: City A, District B` output, but why is not `idno SD: City A, District C` output too? Thanks!

Comment: Why is `idno DC` excluded from the output?

Comment: Sorry, I just added it. I think I phrased the whole question wrong. I should have pointed out more clearly I am interested in the Idno to access the list of places

Comment: There is an ambiguity in the logic here: what if a middle node belongs to more than one parent?

Comment: This in theory could happen, too. But I would be able to restrict that. For now only streets belong to more than one district.

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood the logic, but consider using a key to look up the places by `belongTo`

```
<xsl:key name="places" match="place" use="belongsTo/@active" />
```

You would start off by selecting the first place (where `$idno` is a parameter containing the value you want)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="place[idno = $idno]" />
```

And then in the template matching `place` as well as outputing it, you would process its "children" like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('places', idno)">
```

This would also pass a parameter of the "path" to this current place.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="places" match="place" use="belongsTo/@active" />

  <xsl:param name="idno" select="'CA'" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="place[idno = $idno]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="place">
    <xsl:param name="previous" />
    <xsl:variable name="new" select="$previous[normalize-space()], placeName" />
    <xsl:text>idno {idno}: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$new" separator=", " />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('places', idno)">
      <xsl:with-param name="previous" select="$new" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry I expressed myself badly! What I want is to be able to have an idno and that should output the list according to the list of places

Comment: I've amended my answer, although it doesn't quite match the output you currently expect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using **XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="parent" match="place" use="idno" />

<xsl:template match="place">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(belongsTo)">
            <xsl:text>idno </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="idno" />
            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="placeName" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="belongsTo"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="belongsTo">
    <xsl:text>idno </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="../idno" />
    <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', @active)" mode="path"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="../placeName" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="place" mode="path">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', belongsTo/@active)" mode="path"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="placeName" />
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
idno CA: City A
idno DB: City A, District B
idno DC: City A, District C
idno SD: City A, District B, Street D
idno SD: City A, District C, Street D
idno SE: City A, Street E
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/eiZQaEN/1